# Only some Chinese characters properly displayed in my Xubuntu 18.04 system

Tags: xubuntu, text, unicode, chinese, character-set

I'm working on a CangJie5 typing tutor program in python, and I want to make the system able to display any character that can be typed using the CangJie5 input method.  After making a list of the characters and their codes, I saw that most characters can be displayed using Mousepad, but some show up only as boxes with what I assume is the Unicode value displayed:

[image]

Opening the same text file using Notepad in Windows 7 was able to display all the characters correctly:

[image]

My language selection under language settings is : 漢語（臺灣）{Chinese (Taiwan)}

I wonder what needs to be done to allow display of the entire range of Chinese characters on a Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a font which can show all the unicode characters. I suggest you install [HanaMinA](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/).

你的問題是 mousepad 沒有選用能顯示罕用中文的字型。如果你的 Linux 系統已有此類字型，mousepad 就要選用它們。若無，請安裝「花園明朝體 HanaMinA 和 HanaMinB」。

Use this command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-hanazono
```

Comment: Yes, changing the font solved the problem.  In fact, I already had some fonts installed capable of displaying the characters that had not been displaying.  Thank you for your answer.